# How to convert a string into an array with jagged arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, jagged-arrays

I am writing a function that receives a string like the following format:

```
"Fred:Corwill;Wilfred:Corwill;Barney:Tornbull;Betty:Tornbull;Bjon:Tornbull;Raphael:Corwill;Alfred:Corwill"
```

I want to push it into an array and then transform each key value in a jagged array like this:

```
[["Fred":]["Corwill";]["Alfred:"]["Corwill"]]
```

I tried by creating one initial array with split(), the a second one 
and pushing each part of the string but it didn't work, how can I achieve this
jagged array splitting?

Here is my code:

```
function meeting(s) {
    var initialArray = s.split(' ');
    var jaggedArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < initialArray.length; i++) {
     jaggedArray.push(initialArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: your output array syntax is invalid, having `:` and `;` outside the string in an array is incorrect - are these supposed to be inside the strings?

Comment: And if we assume those should be in the strings, the resulting array isn't jagged. (More accurately: The arrays in the outer array are all of the same length.)  Please provide a syntactically-correct example of the result you're looking for.

Comment: Why does your code split on a space, when there are no spaces in the input string?

Comment: Without being all sure what you're trying to achieve, as I don't understand the reason for it to be "jagged" in this case. I guess it's something like this, that you're looking for => https://jsfiddle.net/1mo5p6ed/

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitMulti(str, tokens){
    var tempChar = tokens[0]; // We can use the first token as a temporary join character
    for(var i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++){
        str = str.split(tokens[i]).join(tempChar);
    }
    str = str.split(tempChar);
    return str;
}

var temp_result = splitMulti(yourString, [':', ';']) // or you can use regex
var final_result = [];
for (var i=0; i<temp_result.length; i++) {
  result.push([temp_result[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your attempt isn't doing much to achieve your desired result as you are splitting by a space `.split(" ")`, but your string has no spaces, and thus this doesn't achieve much at all.

Instead, you can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to split your current string. By using a regular expression, you are able to more precisely control how your string is split. Below, I have used:

```
/(\w+[:;])/
```

Here I am splitting the string by word characters (consecutive) (`\w+`), either followed by a semicolon (`;`) or a colon (`:`).

This, however, will return a one-dimensional array, with additional `""` (empty) strings within it. Thus, I have also used [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to remove your empty strings and put each split value into its own array, thus giving you your result.

See working example below:

```js
const str = "Fred:Corwill;Wilfred:Corwill;Barney:Tornbull;Betty:Tornbull;Bjon:Tornbull;Raphael:Corwill;Alfred:Corwill",

res = str.split(/(\w+[:;])/).reduce((acc, wrd) => wrd ? [...acc, [wrd]] : acc, []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

To split the string by either `:` or `;`, you can simply use regex to get the desired result, in the `.split()` method.

```
const names = "Fred:Corwill;Wilfred:Corwill;Barney:Tornbull;Betty:Tornbull;Bjon:Tornbull;Raphael:Corwill;Alfred:Corwill"

const separatedNames = names.split(/:|;/) 

console.log(separatedNames) // => ["Fred", "Corwill", ...]
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/1mo5p6ed/